# Missing Method Exception Xamarin

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have created an xamarin app with sqlite connection. and When i run this code, it cause an exception:

```
public List<string> GetTpe(string word)
    {
        return dbConnection.Query<string>("Select * From Entries Where Entries.word =?", word).ToList();
    }
```

this is my class Entries:

```
public class Entries
{
    public Entries()
    {

    }

    public Entries(string word)
    {
        this.word = word;
    }
    public Entries(string word, string wordtype, string definition)
    {
        this.word = word;
        this.type = wordtype;
        this.defn = definition;
    }   
    public string word
    { get; set; }

    public string type
    { get; set; }

    public string sdex { get; set; }
    public int wlen { get; set; }

    public string defn
    { get; set; }

    //public List<string> Word { get; set; }


}
```

This is the exception: System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'System.String' not found.

Please Help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SQL query is returning `Entries` objects, not `string`.

```
Query<string>("Select * From Entries Where Entries.word = ?", word)
```

If you are trying to return only a List of `string` and that `string` is a field in the record, lets break it down into its components:

```
var entriesList = conn.Query<Entries>("Select * From Entries Where Entries.word =?", word);
var stringEnumuerationOfDefn = entriesList.Select(entries => entries.defn);
var stringListOfDefn = stringEnumuerationOfDefn.ToList();
```

Update:

```
conn.Insert(new Entries { word = "someWord", defn = "defn1", sdex = "sdex1" });
string wordFilter = "someWord";
var entriesList = conn.Query<Entries>("Select * From Entries Where Entries.word = ? ", word); // new string[1] { word });
var wordEnumueration = entriesList.Select(entries => entries.defn);
var wordList = wordEnumueration.ToList();
foreach (var word in wordList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word)
}
```

Comment: First. thank you again. but when i debuged, i found something. This code: conn.Query<Entries>("Select * From Entries Where Entries.word =?", word); It return nothing. So, what happened to it?